# PrimeFaces internationalization

Tags: jsf, primefaces

I haves a small problem.

I created a simple front-end in JSF technology. I want to ensure internationalization so that the application is available in two languages.

I have separate files for translating texts, e.g. x.x=something

And now, typing #{msg ["x.x"]} for the http://java.sun.com/jsf/html or other standard component, e.g.

```
 <h:form>
      #{msg["x.x"]}
 </h:form>
```

everything is OK, the browser displays "something" for me.

But when I want to use the Prime Faces component (http://primefaces.org/ui), e.g.

```
 <p:panelmenu>
     <p:submenu label="SomeLabel"}>
         <p:menuitem value=#{msg["x.x"]} action="#{y.y}"/>
     </p:submenu>
 </p:panelmenu>
```

it does not work anymore.

Anyone have an idea or knowledge how to solve it?

Comment: Start by clarifying 'does not work anymore', post version info. Etc and does it work in a other components, including plain jsf ones? Lots and lots of basic developer/debug thing you can and **should** do yourself

Comment: Furthermore let us know which versions of jsf, primefaces you are using, with the amount of information you are giving us it's very hard to help you

Answer (score 1):

Could ou try this code ? The double quotes should be placed around the value.

```
 <p:panelmenu>
     <p:submenu label="SomeLabel"}>
         <p:menuitem value="#{msg['x.x']}" action="#{y.y}"/>
     </p:submenu>
 </p:panelmenu>
```

Comment: I missed that (stupid me) but I would have suspected real explict errors then. So if there are no errors that would be weird and if there are, the original post is not the best...